# How to make OpenWRT only route some clients through a VPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, openwrt, wireguard

I have an openWRT router and would like only certain client devices' traffic to be routed through a VPN to the internet.  How can I do this with openWRT or similar router software?  VPN client software cannot be put onto the client devices.  The VPN is either wireguard or openVPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want "[Policy-Based Routing](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/routing/pbr)" which is provided by the `pbr` and `luci-app-pbr` (web interface) packages. Read through the [documentation](https://docs.openwrt.melmac.net/pbr/) to configure it for your use case.